# Admissible rule in classic logic

Tags: propositional-calculus

The classical propositional logic admits the concept of admissible rule, and would like some examples of propositional calculus with the 'admissible rule', on wikipedia I don't quite understand...

Comment: Please expand on your question. What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 3):

A rule $R= \langle S_0, \ldots, S_n, S \rangle$ is said to be a *derivable* in a *proof system* $\mathcal T$, if for each instance $S_0,\ldots, S_n,S$ there is a deduction of $S$ from the $S_i$ be means of the *primitive* rules of $\mathcal T$.

That is to say, in this deduction the $S_i$ are treated as additional axioms.

If we can consider the *natural deduction* proof system, we can derive from the primitive rules the *derived* rule :

> $A \land B \to C \vdash A \to (B \to C)$.

A rule $R$ is said to be *admissible* for $\mathcal T$, if for all instances $S_0,\ldots, S_n,S$ it is the case that :

> if for all $i \le n \ \ \vdash S_i$, then $\vdash S$.

---

See :

- Jan von Plato, [Elements of Logical Reasoning](https://books.google.it/books?id=QrdEAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA47) (2013), page 47 and 58 :

> A derivable rule is admissible, but not necessarily the other way around.
>
> Consider next the law of double negation: $¬¬A \to A$. If it is derivable [in intuitionsitic logic], the instance with $A ∨ ¬A$ in place of $A$, i.e., $¬¬(A ∨ ¬A) \to
> A ∨ ¬A$, is in particular derivable. [I.e.] if $¬¬ A \to A$ is derivable in intuitionistic logic, also $A ∨ ¬A$ is. Thus, that step constitutes an *admissible* rule.
>
> It is a logical fallacy to conclude from such admissibility that the implication $(¬¬A \to A) \to (A∨¬A)$ is *derivable*.

We have that the [admissible rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_rule) are those inference rules which can be consistently employed in derivations in a given system, i.e. they preserve the set of provable theorems.

We say that a system is *structurally complete* when the classes of *admissible* and *derivable* rules coincide; these systems are in some sense "self-containded" : their deductive apparatus generates all inference rules consistent with them.

In this sense, *classical propositional calculus* is structurally complete.

See :

- Vladimir Rybakov, [Admissibility of logical inference rules](https://books.google.it/books?id=ChYWlQEACAAJ) (1997).

  ---

See [Intuitionistic Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/), **Ch.4.2 Admissible rules of intuitionistic logic and arithmetic**, for further examples :

- Harrop's rule [1960] :

> if $\vdash (¬A → (B ∨ C))$, then $\vdash (¬A → B) ∨ (¬A → C)$

is *admissible* but not *derivable*, because $(¬A → (B ∨ C)) → (¬A → B) ∨ (¬A → C)$ is not intuitionistically provable.

- Mints' rule :

> if $\vdash ((A → B) → A ∨ C)$, then $\vdash ((A → B) → A) ∨ ((A → B) → C)$.

Comment: To take another example, given $\vdash x=0$ (for free variable $x$), we can substitute $1$ for $0$ to get $\vdash 1=0$, a contradiction, and so derive $\vdash x=1$. Thus $\vdash x=0\implies\vdash x=1$ is admissible. However, $\vdash (x=0\to x=1)$ is not derivable because if it was we could substitute $0$ for $x$ to get $\vdash 0=1$.