# Deduction theorem in modal logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I am looking for a semantic for deduction theorem in modal logic,I wanna find a semantic way to prove this theorem,but I wasn't successful.tnx for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can see :

- Raul Hakli & Sara Negri, [Does the deduction theorem fail for modal logic](http://www.helsinki.fi/~negri/selected_pub/dedthm.pdf) (2010), for a detailed discussion of the *Deduction Th* in modal logic.

See in particular page 6 for a discussion about an :

> argument for the failure of the deduction theorem [...] based on Kripke semantics.

---

The "issue" with the proof of the *Deduction Th* for modal logic is the "interaction" with the *Necessitation rule* : NEC.

If we consider the following proof from premises :

1) $P$ --- premise

2) $\square P$ --- from 1) by NEC

we have a proof of $\square P$ from $P$, i.e. $P \vdash \square P$.

Thus, with an "unrestricted" *Deduction Th* we can derive the *invalid* :

> $P \to \square P$.

See Sider's book suggested in Bruno's answer below, for the restrictions to be applied in order to prove the *Deduction Th* in some systems of modal logic.

Comment: tnx,but I can't undrestand this sentence  in page 6  "In more general terms, the above statement is actually asking more than the deduction
theorem, as it hides an inference from admissibility to derivability." I wasn't able to find the reason of relation between this sentence and cut example.

Comment: @fatima - regarding *admissibility* vs *derivability* of rules, see this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184007/admissible-rule-in-classic-logic). In *classical* logic the two concepts coincide; not so in other logics, like the *intuitionistic logic* or *modal* system. See there for references.

Answer (score 1):

For a more basic account of the subject you can refer to:

- Theodore Sider, [Logic for Philosophy](http://tedsider.org/books/lfp.html), Ch. 6, p. 178

The author provides simple proofs of soundness, completeness and the deduction theorem for a variety of modal systems.

However, the book does not cover [strong soundness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness#Strong_soundness) and strong completeness though, since the notion of proof from a set involves more complicated issues with the presence of the *necessitation rule* (see Mauro's answer above).

Comment: tnx for your contribiution!