# How to show that a valid rule is not derivable in intuitionistic propositional calculus.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, intuitionistic-logic

First a word on notation, let the following be an inference rule that takes $\Gamma$ (a set of well-formed formulas) as premises and has $\psi$ (a well-formed formula) as a conclusion.

This is represented as

$$ \text{In:}\;\; \Gamma \\ \text{Out:}\;\; \psi $$

I'm using this two-line notation as a representation for an inference rule as a mathematical object, without ascribing any properties to it. By *mentioning* an inference rule in this way, I don't intend to make it part of the deductive system by fiat.

I want to show that the following rule is valid but not derivable in intuitionistic propositional calculus, since it is mentioned in passing in [this paper](https://www.irif.fr/%7Eroziere//admiss/mscs93.pdf), which I'm currently trying to read and make sense of.

$$ \text{In:} \;\; \lnot \alpha \to \beta \lor \gamma \\ \text{Out:} \;\;(\lnot\alpha \to\beta) \lor (\lnot\alpha\to\gamma) $$

Proving that it's valid seems fairly straightforward. I'm using the [Heyting algebra semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic#Heyting_algebra_semantics) described here in an extremely naive way to show this. Let $A, B, G$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the standard topology. Let $E$ be defined as $\text{int}(A^c)$. Note that $E = \text{int}(E)$, i.e. $E$ is open. I'm pretty sure that showing that the conclusion is always a superset of the premise demonstrates the validity of the inference rule. The superset property seems like it would force the conclusion to be true when the premises are true, which is what we want out of an inference rule.

$$ \text{int}(E \cup B\cup G) \subset E \cup B \cup G $$
$$ \text{int}(E \cup B \cup G) \subset E \cup B \cup E \cup G $$
$$ \text{int}(E \cup B \cup G) \subset \text{int}(E) \cup B \cup \text{int}(E) \cup G $$
$$ \text{int}(E \cup B \cup G) \subset (\text{int}(E) \cup B) \cup (\text{int}(E) \cup G) $$

And now we *un*apply the interpretation, giving our rule as desired.

$$ \text{In:} \;\; \lnot \alpha \to \beta \lor \gamma \\ \text{Out:} \;\;(\lnot\alpha \to\beta) \lor (\lnot\alpha\to\gamma) $$

What's a good technique for showing that the rule is not derivable?

Comment: Maybe useful Vladimir Rybakov, [Admissibility of logical inference rules (Elsevier,1997)](https://books.google.it/books?id=wMSyw310EDgC&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Just a comment: to make sense of the claim that a proof rule is not derivable, you need to specify the proof system, and "intuitionistic propositional calculus" does not uniquely specify a proof system. There are many equivalent proof systems for intuitionistic propositional logic, some of which might actually have the rule in question as a basic rule!

Comment: @AlexKruckman The most common proof system I've seen for IPC is the one corresponding to the simply typed lambda calculus extended with binary products and binary sums. Does that have a name?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any surefire ways to specify a proof system other than listing the rules explicitly or giving a reference to a place where the rules are listed explicitly. I'm not even sure what exactly you mean by "the one corresponding to...." in your comment. Enough different authors have published slightly different variants of all the different paradigms that it's a real mess out there! That said, I'm not an expert on proof theory - maybe someone can correct me (@MauroALLEGRANZA ?).

Comment: In my comments above, I misunderstood what "derivable" means. It seems the standard meaning of "derivable" is (sound and complete) proof-system independent: it just means $\vdash \bigwedge \Gamma\rightarrow \psi$. Still, it's worth saying that it's always a good idea to specify your proof system.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184007/admissible-rule-in-classic-logic) with some link as well as Grigori Mints, [Derivability of admissible rules (1976)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01084082) and Rosalie Iemhoff, [On the Admissible Rules of Intuitionistic Propositional Logic (1970)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2580899_On_the_Admissible_Rules_of_Intuitionistic_Propositional_Logic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your translation to topological semantics is not quite right. $p\rightarrow q$ translates to $\text{int}(P^{c}\cup Q)$, not $\text{int}(P\cup Q)$. So what you wanted to show was $$\text{int}(\text{cl}(A)\cup B\cup G) \subseteq \text{int}(\text{cl}(A)\cup B) \cup \text{int}(\text{cl}(A)\cup G),$$ using the fact that $E^{c} = (\text{int}(A^c))^c = \text{cl}(A)$. Your proof doesn't work, since it relied on openness of $E$, and $\text{cl}(A)$ is not open in general.

In fact, this inclusion is not true in general. Take $A = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}^+} (\frac{1}{2n+1},\frac{1}{2n})$, $B = (-\infty,0)$, and $G = (0,\infty)$. Then $0\in \text{int}(\text{cl}(A)\cup B\cup G) = \mathbb{R}$, but $0\notin \text{int}(\text{cl}(A)\cup B) \cup \text{int}(\text{cl}(A)\cup G)$.

Ok, but what does this actually show? It shows that when $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are propositional constants, $\lnot \alpha\rightarrow (\beta\lor \gamma)\not\models (\lnot \alpha\rightarrow \beta)\lor(\lnot \alpha\rightarrow \gamma)$. Equivalently, by completeness of IPL, $$\not\vdash (\lnot \alpha\rightarrow (\beta\lor \gamma))\rightarrow ((\lnot \alpha\rightarrow \beta)\lor(\lnot \alpha\rightarrow \gamma)).$$ That is, in the language of the paper you linked to, this rule is not *derivable*.

To show the rule is *admissible* means something different: Whenever we substitute sentences $\varphi_\alpha$, $\varphi_\beta$, and $\varphi_\gamma$ for $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$, respectively, we have $$\text{If }\vdash \lnot \varphi_\alpha\rightarrow (\varphi_\beta\lor \varphi_\gamma),\text{ then }\vdash (\lnot \varphi_\alpha\rightarrow \varphi_\beta)\lor(\lnot \varphi_\alpha\rightarrow \varphi_\gamma).$$
Usually, to show that a rule is admissible, one has to do some induction on proofs. It seems that the original reference for admissibility of this rule is Theorem 3.1 in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.2307/2964334) (Ronald Harrop, Concerning Formulas of the Types $A\rightarrow B\lor C$, $A\rightarrow (Ex)B(x)$, J. Symbolic Logic Volume 25, Issue 1 (1960), 27-32; [jstor](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2964334).)

Comment: The text around Proposition 1.2.1 on page 2 says that the rule in question doesn't add any new theorems. I assumed that meant that the $\mathbb{R}$-translation would have to send the truth value of its premises to a "better" truth value to prevent "backsliding" (note the heavy scare quotes), but now that I think about it that seems totally unjustified.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a Kripke model that is a tree of four nodes: A root $r$ and three children $a,b,c$ of $r$. Lat $\alpha$ be true only at $a$, $\beta$ only at $b$, and $\gamma$ only at $c$. Then $\neg\alpha\to(\beta\lor\gamma)$ is true at $r$ but $(\neg\alpha\to\beta)\lor(\neg\alpha\to\gamma)$ is not.